# Alternating colors in HTML table rows doesn't work

Tags: html, css, jstl, html-table, tablerow

I've created a JSP that has the following style,

```
<style type="css/text">
tr.color1{background-color:#00FCFF;}
tr.color2{background-color:#c1bfbb;}
</style>
```

I model an attribute in the JSP and render a table. Since I iterate over the List that is modelled in my JSP, I have to set up a logic for alternating HTML table rows.

I have used JSTL and have the following code:

```
 <c:forEach items="${rSList}" var="rS" varStatus="rowCounter">
      <tr class="${rowCounter.index % 2 == 0  ? 'color2':'color1'}">
          <td style="padding-left: 4px;" >
              <font face="verdana"><c:out value="${rS.NAME}" /></font>
          </td>

          <td style="padding-left: 4px;" >  
              <font face="verdana"><c:out value="${rS.AVAILABLE}" /></font>
          </td>

          <td style="padding-left: 4px;" >  
              <font face="verdana"><c:out value="${rS.OWNER}" /></font>
          </td>
```

I used `Firebug` and saw that indeed the class get alternated as :

```
<tr class="color2">
<!- td data gets displayed here without color2 background-->

<tr class="color1">
<!- td data gets displayed here without color1 background-->

<tr class="color2">
<tr class="color1">
<tr class="color2">
```

This means that the class is getting picked but the background color doesn't change. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are doing should work as nothing is wrong, it can be related to specificity like say you are using a `class`, but some other rule is more specific like

```
#demo table tr {
    background: #fff;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KAH46/1/) **FAILS** (Specificity matters)

So in the above example, though the classes are applied and `tr`should take the background, it won't take as you must have declared a more specific rule before, or lets say you are using `!important`. You can inspect the element and see what color is applied from which selector/rule.

Also if you want to save your markup to a great extent, you can simply use the CSS below, which will apply to odd and even rows of your table, without declaring classes, like

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f00;
}

table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: #000;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/KAH46/)

Comment: Thanks @Mr. Alien. Really appreciate your help The second solution did the trick. I wonder what was wrong with my approach. Does this mean that declaring the CSS using `nth` child will overrride any rules applied to the table by the outer CSS's.. ?

Comment: @user2339071 than am sure it's the specificity issue, if you want to learn, just google out, CSS Specificity, and it doesn't mean it will override if you use `:nth`, it's just that the rule you are using is more specific, and about the `odd` and `even`, this gets real handy while using tables, also make sure you use class because the selector I gave you will apply to all tables, I hope you are aware of that :)

Comment: Yup I know. :P .. Besides I wouldn't mind giving the alternate feel to all of my table. :D .. +1 for the solution and the guidance. Thanks. :)

Comment: @user2339071 I would also like to point out that you are using deprecated `font` tag, instead write the font size, family, weight in your css like `table.class tr td {/* style goes here */}`